# How can I receive Play 2.0 debugging emails?

Tags: java, exception, playframework, smtp, playframework-2.0

In the world of Python & Pylons, configuring email alerts for server crashes is fairly direct, via the configuration file:

```
email_to = engineering@mysite.com
error_email_from = noreply@mysite.com
smtp_server = smtp.sendgrid.net
smtp_username = myusername
smtp_password = mypassword
smtp_use_tls = false
```

I've been trying to set up the equivalent sort of debugging emails in a Play 2.1.2 project, to no success.  I noticed Play used to have a fairly direct setup for this stuff back in version 1.0 (documented [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#mail.debug)).  But the equivalent 2.0 documentation doesn't exist.

What is the proper way of setting up a play 2.0 project, so that my team receives an email every time the server crashes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SettingsLogger) uses [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as logging framework. So you can easily configure a [SMTP appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) to send errors per mail.